# LLVM CreateFCmpONE equivalent for integer

Tags: c++, llvm

What is llvm equivalent of `Builder.CreateFCmpONE` for integer data type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is instruction for compare not equal for ints it depends on what your end goal is, but this might do the trick `Builder.CreateICmpNE`